# Are Debian- and RedHat-style repositories compromised by Heartbleed OpenSSL bug?

Tags: debian, rhel, security, openssl

The [Heartbleed](http://heartbleed.com) exploit ([CVE-2014-0160](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-0160)) makes SSL connections using OpenSSL vulnerable to private key leakage.

Does it mean that official update channels in RHEL/CentOS/etc. and Debian/Ubuntu shall be considered compromised?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Packages and lists in the Debian / Ubuntu repositories are signed by GPG keys. The transport is not secured with SSL (packages are transferred over just over plain ftp or http). I am not that familiar with RHEL / CentOS, but if RPMs are signed too, then the same should apply.

Comment: RPMs are indeed signed with GPG.