# root login silently fails

Tags: ssh, root, su

After some months of not touching it I wanted to login to one of our virtual servers to update OpenSSL, because of the heartbleed thing. The server is running Debian 7, `sudo` is not installed.

I tried three ways:

1. `ssh root@server`, password is accepted and then:

   ```
   Could not chdir to home directory /home/root: No such file or directory
   Connection to server closed.
   ```
2. Logging in as some other user and then `su - root`.

   ```
   No directory, logging in with HOME=/
   ```

   Then I am back to my usual shell, not logged in as root.
3. Logging in as some other user and then `su root`. This gives nothing, I am simply back to the usual prompt, still logged in as the other user and not root.

I have no chance to manually restart the server before monday. Is there anything I could try to do to get a root shell? May the server be compromised and how could I check that (without root access)? Thank you!

In all cases, when typing the wrong password the machine complains as usual.

`/root` does exist and `/etc/passwd` lists the correct directory. I have no idea why ssh believes differently.

---

This may be important: Checking `$?` after the unsuccessful `su` call gives me a `1`, which is `System or authentication failure` according to the man page of su. How can I make it more verbose?

---

As requested below, the output of `ssh -v`:

```
Last login: Fri Apr 11 17:47:46 2014 from some_client
Could not chdir to home directory /home/root: No such file or directory
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to server closed.
Transferred: sent 3136, received 2448 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 299688.7, received 233940.7
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Not an answer. But if your server is running Debian 7, it is highly likely that the `OpenSSL` version would be 0.X which does not have any issue. :)

Comment: It is `OpenSSL 1.0.1f`

Comment: Oh ok. In that case, you need to fix it :) I would highly recommend you to follow the steps mentioned in @Gile's post :) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123711/how-do-i-recover-from-the-heartbleed-bug-in-openssl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**All the below contents are from** [here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/servers/133635-solved-could-not-chdir-home-directory-root.html).

The error message implies that, the root's home directory is missing. You can recreate it with `mkdir /root`, but it'll be empty.

Normally, you should not log in directly as root. All direct root access should be disabled for remote logins and X sessions, although allowing root access from text-mode terminals can be a lifesaver when things go wrong. You should always log in as a real user and then use `su` or `su -` (and the root password, of course) to change to the root user.

However, in your case, the su is not effective since you still do not have the `/root` directory.

After creating /root directory, you still will have some default files missing.

The files you need are the default `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`, these should be copied into `/root`. The leading `.` means the files are hidden, so you might have to do `ls -a` to see them.

**EDIT**

The actual issue turned out to be, for the root user, the shell was set to be `/bin/false`. This can be verified by issuing the command,

`getent passwd root`

In this case, the output of the above command turned out to be,

`root:x:0:0:Netbios Domain Administrator:/home/root:/bin/false`

Which can be changed if you are having a `sudo` user or you should start the machine in `single` mode and edit the above setting.

Comment: Hi Ramesh, thank you for the answer. /root exists and is correctly listed in /etc/passwd.

Comment: May be, is the root password expired?

Comment: Providing the wrong password results in the usual error message. Also I did never set up any expiry, especially not for the root user.

Comment: Can you provide the output of this command `ssh -v root@host`?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: What is the permissions on `/` folder? It should be owned by root only. If you have `sudo` privileges for any user to issue shutdown command, even if you are doing `ssh` to this machine, you can always issue `shutdown -r now` and try restarting the machine.

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 4096 Dec 18 17:52 /`

Comment: Sorry, can you run this command and provide the output? `getent passwd root`

Comment: Ahh, this looks promising. `root:x:0:0:Netbios Domain Administrator:/home/root:/bin/false`
Right, this appears to be an ldap issue, where another root user exists. How can I force su to use the local one?

Comment: Do you have `vipw` enabled in your system?

Comment: it is installed, yes, but without sudo or su working I cannot use it.

Comment: You have to login as single user in the machine and edit the `\etc\passwd` file . Do you have VNC server setup on these machines?

Comment: I don't, but our IT will be able to fix it now that the mistake is located. That will have to wait until monday, though. Thank you very much for your help! I am glad it turned out to be something harmless.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Comment: @janoliver With a shell of `/bin/false` you won't be able to login. Use `su -s /bin/sh`.

Comment: I of course tried that, but somehow it doesn't work. I guess that the system tries to authenticate me against the correct root account and then gets confused. I'll simply wait for our IT to fix it.