# centos update heartbleed bug

Tags: centos, openssl

There are six packages listed for my 32bit system [here](http://people.centos.org/z00dax/disable_heartbeat/i386/Packages/)

Not sure how to go about updating...

Ok I have not done `yum clean all` and `yum update "openssl*"`

but am stuck on following command `lsof -n | grep ssl | grep DEL`  it doesn't work so is it safe to say just restart mysql and then regenerate keys and certificates?

Comment: above is why to be sure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See:  [How do I recover from the Heartbleed bug in OpenSSL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123711/how-do-i-recover-from-the-heartbleed-bug-in-openssl)

Comment: can you answer the added bits i edited at end of my question please?

Comment: Depending on your level of service/demand, you could shut down
services (mysql, httpd, whatever) then do yum updates,
then restart services.  For a hobby/free service, I would do 
that, but for a commercial service I might try to update in place.
YMMV.

Comment: shut down , you mean restart mysql ? or restart server